# Sending messages to multiple elastic search indices

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat, elk

We are running an ELK stack to aggregate all our logs and we have multiple systems. Currently, we have Filebeat configured to log to specific indices based on the system (SystemA, SystemB, SystemC).

I would like to, additionally, send all logs with level ERROR to another index where I would like to collect all errors across systems, but somehow I can't figure out how to get Filebeat to send one message to multiple indices

According to [the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/elasticsearch-output.html#indices-option-es), the first condition that matches will define the index to be used, which sounds to me as if it's not possible to send a message that would match multiple patterns to multiple indices?

What I want to do:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}'
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
  index: "filebeat-external-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  indices:
    - index: "filebeat-error-logs-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when:
        or:
          - equals:
              level: "ERROR"
          - equals:
              level: "error"
    - index: "filebeat-service-a-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when:
        regexp:
          container.name: "^service-a-"
    - index: "filebeat-service-b-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when:
        regexp:
          container.name: "^service-b-"
```

The only way I currently see is to have multiple indices per system and aggregate them in Kibana:

```
output.elasticsearch:
  hosts: '${ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS}'
  username: '${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}'
  password: '${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}'
  index: "filebeat-external-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  indices:
    - index: "error-log-service-a-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when:
        and:
          - equals:
              level: "ERROR"
          - regexp:
              container.name: "^service-a-"
    - index: "service-log-service-a-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
      when:
        and:
          - not:
             - equals:
                level: "ERROR"
          - regexp:
              container.name: "^service-a-"
```

But this would double our number of indices and is code duplication. Am I missing something here, is there an easier way to have a general error-index but still have errors go to the service-specific indices as well?

Comment: I would also be glad if someone can point me to a solution how this might be done in elasticsearch instead of filebeat (copying messages from X indices with level Error to another index)

Comment: Maybe the other way around. You can create index alias matching indices of all systems with filter to error messages only. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/indices-add-alias.html

Comment: We don't really want an index alias as we would like to really have a specific index - so that searching in that index would be faster and we could specify to keep error logs for a longer time. 

We will probably go for introducing logstash as it offers more possibilities, thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: In the end we went for introducing logstash